# SoapUI not checking certificate?

Tags: rest, ssl, https, soapui

My end goal is to setup a RESTful service that requires 2-way (mutual) authentication between client and server. To start with I thought I would setup one-way authentication to get the first half setup and then progress to 2-way.

So, I have created a RESTful service that purely returns the word "Test" and exposed this. I generated a server public/private key and self-signed (using the Java keytool -genkeypair ....) and setup my RESTful service to use this. The service is running on MuleESB.

Now, before adding my new certificate to my client trust store, I thought I would test the service to check that I was getting a certificate error. Now strangely, through the browser and through Postman, I get the correct error; the browser complains that the certificate received cannot be trusted (as I haven't added the root CA to the trust store). However, when I use SOAPUI to test the service it works without complaining about anything. Can anyone help me on why this may be? I need to get SOAPUI working as, when I progress to 2-way authentication I want to be able to specify the certificate to use, something that is not offered by Postman or testing through the Browser.

When I run SOAPUI with SSL Debug running, I can see that it correctly receives my certificate. But, why does it allow the connection to proceed?

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Thread-19, setSoTimeout(60000) called
11:09:31,437 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
11:09:31,437 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: POST /tls_demo HTTP/1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1430129115 bytes = { 169, 90, 188, 193, 157, 139, 108, 202, 210, 247, 133, 120, 10, 158, 27, 16, 64, 185, 132, 252, 160, 132, 134, 143, 10
7, 43 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, T
A_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
TH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SS
_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_
SA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409
9r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
Thread-19, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 149
Thread-19, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1263
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1430129115 bytes = { 53, 109, 252, 185, 170, 82, 228, 217, 216, 171, 31, 216, 97, 146, 131, 246, 22, 186, 112, 91, 84, 70, 120, 245, 133,
171 }
Session ID:  {85, 62, 10, 219, 107, 202, 236, 196, 63, 241, 150, 1, 106, 39, 117, 228, 115, 228, 46, 184, 113, 246, 47, 221, 167, 189, 241, 113, 84, 206, 208,
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=localhost, O=XXX, L=London, ST=London, C=UK
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: ...
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Sun Apr 26 13:34:47 BST 2015,
               To: Sat Jul 25 13:34:47 BST 2015]
  Issuer: CN=localhost, O=XXX, L=London, ST=London, C=UK
  SerialNumber: [    455a97e9]

Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
...                                       n..^
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
...
]
***
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 68526603352329217636640245091574224497038239255373755817696844356233255971246
  public y coord: 21112579998360783627101805895048744731921568253573017990269969136714373392408
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
*** ServerHelloDone
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
ECDH Public value:  { 4, 89, 134, 56, 131, 220, 223, 187, 120, 151, 87, 126, 47, 86, 127, 171, 82, 53, 120, 167, 24, 61, 34, 71, 184, 249, 52, 80, 138, 14, 80
 163, 158, 153, 90, 73, 82, 162, 196, 57, 200, 82, 29, 86, 66, 212, 100, 247, 225, 206, 59, 214, 212, 254, 184, 70, 251, 29, 169, 148, 209, 235, 153 }
Thread-19, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 70
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 37 99 38 FE 85 E7 7B 4B   22 7B 84 4A 09 9E 56 4B  7.8....K"..J..VK
0010: 0F 30 30 BE A8 68 E6 83   E2 4A 26 86 14 1A 20 C6  .00..h...J&... .
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 55 3E 0A DB A9 5A BC C1   9D 8B 6C CA D2 F7 85 78  U>...Z....l....x
0010: 0A 9E 1B 10 40 B9 84 FC   A0 84 86 8F 69 ED D9 2B  ....@.......i..+
Server Nonce:
0000: 55 3E 0A DB 35 6D FC B9   AA 52 E4 D9 D8 AB 1F D8  U>..5m...R......
0010: 61 92 83 F6 16 BA 70 5B   54 46 78 F5 85 90 FE AB  a.....p[TFx.....
Master Secret:
0000: E2 A8 93 EC 8F 94 D7 E4   D3 1E 5D C4 67 CB 04 D8  ..........].g...
0010: A3 DB 9A AA 62 AD A5 E9   82 69 A9 53 73 E9 A3 EA  ....b....i.Ss...
0020: 19 70 2A CC B4 D9 73 A1   45 5D 0E 71 88 F2 87 39  .p*...s.E].q...9
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: 7E 59 8D 23 82 EA 68 09   D6 EB 61 A6 FA 09 83 CA  .Y.#..h...a.....
0010: 82 55 A1 55                                        .U.U
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: 5E B6 5A AB 76 E7 ED 58   C3 F4 54 31 22 C4 17 25  ^.Z.v..X..T1"..%
0010: 7B FB 13 93                                        ....
Client write key:
0000: 3B A8 B0 59 BE 06 91 A0   49 E8 92 E9 0F 65 97 0D  ;..Y....I....e..
Server write key:
0000: 4A 72 09 C2 44 86 3F A4   23 E3 97 44 93 87 6B D2  Jr..D.?.#..D..k.
Client write IV:
0000: 8F 97 2C D0 F2 40 A8 73   73 58 F1 2C A1 0C 9B 4A  ..,..@.ssX.,...J
Server write IV:
0000: BC 6D DF 9D 3B 4D 36 60   9C 1F 42 E9 92 E1 DC E8  .m..;M6`..B.....
Thread-19, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 79, 84, 80, 98, 226, 179, 250, 217, 159, 48, 116, 201 }
***
Thread-19, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
Thread-19, READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
Thread-19, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 251, 97, 234, 50, 100, 163, 171, 163, 81, 10, 21, 147 }
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
Thread-19, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 224
Thread-19, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 896
11:09:31,701 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Thread-19, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 32
Thread-19, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 32
Thread-19, called close()
Thread-19, called closeInternal(true)
Thread-19, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
Thread-19, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 32
Thread-19, called closeSocket(selfInitiated)
11:09:31,714 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Connection shut down
Thread-19, called close()
Thread-19, called closeInternal(true)
11:09:31,866 INFO  [AbstractHttpRequestDesktopPanel] Got response for [https://localhost:8081.Tls_demo:Request 1] in 709ms (6 bytes)
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
```

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

I have run the same test, and I can see it doesn't care about the server certificate. Even when I check "Client Authentication" in the SSL Configuration.